# I Install flutter and add it path also but when i run flutter in cmd it showing nothig nor any error of anything in result

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwY3T.png)
I Install flutter and add it path also but when i run flutter in cmd it showing nothig nor any error of anything in result

I Install flutter and add it path also but when i run flutter in cmd it showing nothig nor any error of anything in result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to setting up Flutter:

-Go to the folder where Flutter is installed (For me its my downloads folder)

-Run the command 'Flutter Doctor' and follow the instructions to set up flutter

-Thats it!

Let me know if that helped you or you need any further clarification

EDIT: Also make sure you set the path to the Flutter Bin folder